# Need help understanding strange effects from improper font size changes

Tags: react-native

I was messing with font sizes and accidentally added `style={fontSize=8}` (I know this is wrong it should be `style={{fontSize:8}}`) I got some very strange effects from it. As I changed the numeric value I would get seemingly random effects. For example if I use `fontSize=3` it would have a green background, 4 would be a blue background, 7 a red outline. I come from a Native iOS development background so I have minimal experience with JavaScript and React Native. Can someone explain to be what is happening here? Why do I not get an error when I try to run this? How is this changing how it displays? I am looking for this to help get me a better understanding of how React Native works.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.dialPadContainer}>
        <View style={styles.keypadContainer}>
          <View style={styles.keyRowContainer}>
            <TouchableHighlight
              style={styles.keyButton}
              onPress={() => {}}
              activeOpacity={75 / 100}
              underlayColor={"rgb(245,166,35)"}>
              <Text style={fontSize=7}>1</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }


 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  dialPadContainer:{
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: "green",
 },
  keypadContainer:{
   flex: 65,
   flexDirection:'column',
   backgroundColor: "rgba(74,144,226,1)",
 },
  keyRowContainer:{
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center',
   flexDirection:'row',
   backgroundColor: "rgba(74,144,226,1)",
 },
  keyButton: {
     flex: 1,
     justifyContent: "center",
     alignItems: "center",
     borderWidth: 1,
     backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
  }
});
```

Comment: may be a bug on their end?  I would open an issue on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues) to see if there is anything further going on for it.  It should have errored out imo as passing anything other than an object of styles is not what is expected.